# Maven client is not able to download artifacts from remote server

Tags: maven-3, nexus

I am stuck with two days and unable to move forward.

We are using nexus repo within our local environment and able to download/transfer artifacts in intranet but now have to expose nexus repo to outside of network through internet.

I used the same maven client and same settings file except the nexus manager URL changes.  unfortunately could not able to download the artificats.

From the browser we could view artifacts from outside of network, problem with only maven client, Error is Not authorized

Help would greatly appreciate.

Thanks
Dorairaj

Comment: Sounds like a networking issue, unrelated to Nexus.

Comment: @Dhorrairaajj, Seems to be a like network issue as pointed by Mark, Would be great if you check your firewall settings and post the logs.